# How to determine the scale of an Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, scale

I have an image that I'm using which is 960x1280.  I have coordinates for a rectangle of x:391 y:772, x:574 y:772, x:574 y:870, x:391 y:870 which allows me to put the rectangle in the proper spot IF the image is still 960x1280.  Of course, when I'm in Xcode, the screen size is 375x667.

When drawing the rectangle with the above coordinates, the rectangle is no longer visible.  If just use the screen scale of 3 (`UIScreen.main.scale`) it's not accurate either.

I create a UIImageView that has constraints of 0 for all four sides and using aspect `.fit` or `.fill`.  How do I now know the proper scale of the image so the rectangle is drawn in the right spot?

Thanks

Comment: Apologies, but what is "*391 772, 574 772, 574 870, 391 870"*? If it's a `CGRect` of some sort, could you provide `CGRect` coordinates? CGRect(x:y:width:height:)`? And what do you mean by: *"Of course, when I'm in Xcode, the screen size is 375x667"*? Xcode doesn't decide the screen size, the *device* does. (Since you tagged this [uiimage] I can safely assume you are talking iOS, correct?

Comment: Here's something I think might be helpful. (1) Don't worry about `UIImage.contentMode, just worry about *placement*. In fact, don't even use a `UIImage`, just a different colored `UIView`. (2) And learn to use auto layout constraints, including safe areas. (3) Now that you've got a `UIView` properly placed - *no matter the device* - change it to a `UIImage` with the same constraints.

Comment: (4) Now worry about the content mode and/or scale. Remember, let iOS do your work. If you wish to know the *screen* scale, ask for it. If you want to "fit" the image into the view - no matter the screen size or scale - set it to aspect fit. And if you want your image to "fill" the entire frame of you image view, - set it to aspect fill.